Why I'm having Missing Entitlement warning in WKWebView?
I'm using WKWebView to open web-page in-app.
I'm opening the view as a popup. Here's my code in the popup-view "WebkitViewController":
override func viewDidLoad()
{
  super.viewDidLoad()
    
  self.webview.navigationDelegate = self
  self.webview.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://mywebsite.com")!))
}
..
extension WebkitViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {}
  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {}
  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {}
}

Next I'm opening the view as a popup on button press:
@IBAction func onContactRequest(_ sender: Any)
{
  let webview = UIStoryboard.webviewViewController() as! WebkitViewController
  self.navigationController?.present(webview, animated: true)
}

I also added following in Info.plist:
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>

Running on simulator iOS 18.1, it opens the popup, loads the webpage correctly, but as soon I dismiss the popup, I'm having following warning in debug console:

Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "((target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.developer.web-browser-engine.rendering AND target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.developer.web-browser-engine.networking AND target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.developer.web-browser-engine.webcontent))" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=((target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.developer.web-browser-engine.rendering AND target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.developer.web-browser-engine.networking AND target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.developer.web-browser-engine.webcontent))}>

It do not crash the app. But I couldn't found a related discussion on this, but since this related to entitlements I'm bit worried. Is this something that I need to be worried during app submission? How can I resolve this if it is.

You might like to set the web view's navigation delegate to nil before dismissing the popup.
